# Short length asymmetric encryption?

Tags: encryption, rsa, reference-request

I want to send out short messages to the world which listeners could verify to be send from me.

The way this is usually done is to encrypt the message with a private key where the readers decrypt it with my public key. My problem is that I need small messages, smaller than 64 bytes in base64, plain RSA won't work since the algorithm makes the encrypted message around 128 bytes.

Can someone suggest the name of an algorithm to me that may work?

Comment: Actually you are looking for a signature scheme not an encryption scheme. [BLS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLS_(cryptography)) signatures are very short, but [ECDSA](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA) is also ok for your requirements and implementations are widely available.

Comment: "(I) encrypt the message with a private key where the readers decrypt it with my public key" is a sin in terminology. That should be "(I) _sign_ the message with a private key where the readers _verify_ it with my public key". The change in terminology also comes with a change in the appropriate methodology, even though in RSA the modular exponentiation remains the same. In RSA, using _only_ exponentiation is called textbook RSA or naked RSA, and is unsafe (often for encryption, most often for signature).

Answer (score 4):

Note that encrypting "the message with a private key where the readers decrypt it with my public key"

is usually insecure, although there are [signatures with message recovery](http://issuu.com/sep2011--now/docs/ijics081) that are presumably secure.

The canonical short signature scheme is [BLS](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf).

The main alternative that I'm aware of is the [random-oracle part of this paper](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~xb/eurocrypt04a/bbsigs.pdf),

although [that scheme cannot safely sign a large number of messages](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/221.pdf).

Comment: Signature schemes with message recovery only aim at saving bandwidth, compared to signature schemes with appendix. For example, the signature scheme of ISO/IEC 9796-2 allows to convey a 480-byte message as a 514-byte cryptogram (assuming 4096-bit RSA and SHA-256 hash), when SSA schemes of PKCS#1 would make that a 992-byte cryptogram.